# Java Apache Arrow Copy data from one VectorSchemaRoot to another

Tags: java, apache-arrow

If I have a `VectorSchemaRoot` that already contains data using the the [Java Apache Arrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/java/index.html) library, how would I go about copying that data to another `VectorSchemaRoot`?

Answer (score 1):

What you most commonly would want to do is to create a TransferPair object for each Vector in the source VectorSchemaRoot, to transfer its buffers to new vectors in the second one.

In this case what you have, though, is not really a "copy" as the data is passed from one VSR to another, rather than copied. A typical use-case for this approach is using VectorSchemaRoots in a pipeline where they process data sequentially.

If you could say a bit more about what you're trying to accomplish I might be able to provide a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I implemented it. Make sure you close the `originalRoot`, otherwise you'll get a memory leak exception. Also, `getAllocator()` creates a child allocator from `RootAllocator`, i.e. don't create a new root — you'll get another exception there must be the same shared root.

```
  private VectorSchemaRoot cloneRoot(VectorSchemaRoot originalRoot) {
    VectorSchemaRoot theRoot = VectorSchemaRoot.create(originalRoot.getSchema(), getAllocator());
    VectorLoader loader = new VectorLoader(theRoot);
    VectorUnloader unloader = new VectorUnloader(originalRoot);
    try (ArrowRecordBatch recordBatch = unloader.getRecordBatch()) {
      loader.load(recordBatch);
    }
    return theRoot;
  }
```